# Is it okay to caulk around floating panels to close air leaks in my wood door?

Tags: doors

Front door is wood with floating panels. Air is infiltrating around the edges of the panels.

The entry is double arched wooden doors. Looks like a castle. Can see a bit of unstained wood at some of the panel edges as if it has moved. There is moulding that sits at the stile? and panel. In the summer, I can see daylight around some of the moulding. The door is under an overhang. Does not usually receive rain unless it is a one-off, freak blowing storm. Late summer sun does hit a portion of it. WInter lows last year got to -9F and summer highs near 100F. Right now humidity is 43%.

Is it okay to use caulk around the edges of the panels? If it's okay, should it be used on the exterior, interior, or does it matter?

Comment: I would not caulk the front door floating panels. You might be able to seal the joints with tung oil or exterior stain but still have the panels mobile. Squirt or daub tung oil or stain around the joint outside while simultaneously using a shop vac on the inside to pull the tung oil or stain into the joint. The stain could be colorless stain or a matching color.

Comment: Our front door has 32 floating panels and when we moved in 47 years ago a blowing rain would go right through and we would have water dripping down the inside of the door. Under the guidance and supervision of the woodworking expert next door I took the door off the hinges, laid it horrizontal, stripped the paint, put on good quality stain and then tung oil. This sealed the door and it is still in perfect shape. Ten yearrs ago we did put on a storm door. House is north facing so this does not make a solar oven.

Comment: Supposedly a storm door over a south facing door exposed to direct sun makes a solar oven which will damage the door. A neighbor on the next street has that situation and the door has been OK for 10 years in Dallas TX sun.

Comment: @JimStewart — I don’t want to diminish your experience, but I can’t imagine how oil can serve to block a gap.

Comment: Detail photos would be great. Good solutions may depend on specific configuration.

Comment: Are the panels held in by removable sticking on one side of the door? (You’d see hints of nails and perhaps a crack between the rails/stiles and the moulding.)

Comment: What sort of climate do you live in? Is the door exposed to rain, or is it under a roof?

Comment: An exterior door with floating panels seems like a terrible idea. Even if the cracks are airtight, the panels will provide very little thermal insulation. The best solution is to replace the door; the second best is to put a storm door over it.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The entry is double arched wooden doors. Looks like a castle. Can see a bit of unstained wood at some of the panel edges as if it has moved. There is moulding that sits at the stile? and panel. In the summer, I can see daylight around some of the moulding. The door is under an overhang. Does not usually receive rain unless it is a one-off, freak blowing storm. Late summer sun does hit a portion of it. WInter lows last year got to -9F and summer highs near 100F. Right now humidity is 43%.

Comment: Generally speaking panels in doors are floating but the joints are supposed to be tight enough and tortuous enough to not let air infiltrate. If the OP can see daylight through some joints, then more action than just staining the joints would be necessary, but I would still start with that. Good quality exterior stain can fill joints. Then fill where necessary with epoxy.  Our front door is a single 36" x 79" stain grade which is in perfect condition, tract house built 1970.  Maybe the volume builder put in well made front doors.

Comment: A hand crafted Victorian front door at the New Yorkshire Workshop.
 https://youtu.be/3gJWQpEjoGU?si=gEWrdxME7LUfGD7H  https://youtu.be/iCg3-YsOiPo?si=Ru5SXWtddBFwX572

Comment: @MikeBaranczak Most exterior doors, if made of wood (and the most expensive ones are), are of floating raised panel construction. If you tried to glue the panels in place, either they'd crack or the frames around them would from wood movement from season to season.

Comment: I would guess that @JimStewart's suggestion of applying some sort of oil worked because it increased the moisture content of the wood, causing the panels to swell and seal themselves into the dados again. This leads me to believe that the panels may have been cut too thin for the dados they sit in, allowing air to get by in the first place.

Comment: "I can see daylight around some of the moulding." @user178817, sounds like the panels may have been cut a bit too small. This sounds like a _very_ expensive, probably custom door. You might be able to find a local woodworker who would be willing to take on the task of disassembling it (not easy) and cutting new panels to better fit the spaces allocated for them.

Comment: I would try to get oil based stain into the joints, let it dry then fill gaps with tung oil, wax or other hydrophobic coating to prevent water from getting into the joints. This might reduce air inflitration to a very low level. If you have a gap that light is showing through perhaps you could shift a panel in it pocket to cover the gap.

Comment: We’d love to help, but need pics, preferably closeups of both sides of the door where a panel meets the rail or stile.

Answer (score 2):

Just to propose another solution: Install a storm door. My storm door stops drafts; the wood door only has to look nice and stop intruders.

Comment: We installed a moderately heavy duty storm door which has full glass and doesn't detract from appearance. A lot of the time we leave the inward opening wooden door open to let in light through the storm door. Our house is north facing and the front yard is "natural" with thick trees and tall shrubs. The walkway from the front door curves 15 ft to the west before turning N to the sidewalk so passersby on the sidewalk can't see directly inside but we can see out to the sidewalk and street.